# How do I build a trapezoidal sunburst?

Tags: swift, swiftui, shapes

I am wanting to build a trapezoidal sunburst effect in SwiftUI. My designs requirements are a static image, but I need something more reusable and dynamic, because I can't replicate the view as an image in SwiftUI without some incredibly hacky workarounds. My solution is to rebuild this view, natively, rather than relying on the `.png` asset.

##### The View to be replicated.

[image]

##### The view I have now.

[image]

##### The code behind what I have now.

```
struct SunRay: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        Path { path in
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.4, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width  * 0.6, y: rect.height))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.8, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width * 0.2, y: 0))
        }
    }
}

struct RadialSunburstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            HStack(spacing: -8) {
                Group {
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: -40))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: -30))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: -20))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: -10))
                    SunRay()
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: 10))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: 20))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: 30))
                    SunRay().rotation(Angle(degrees: 40))
                }
            }
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height)
            .foregroundColor(.white.opacity(0.05))
            .clipped()
            .background (
                LinearGradient.blueGradient
                    .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.15)
            )
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height * 0.15)
        .clipped()
        .cornerRadius(20)
    }
}
```

As you can see, my code is closeish? I'm not really sure if I'd call it a win at this point. The largest issue I have right now is that when I attempt to use it in another view, with `RadialSunburstView()` I can't actually add any horizontal padding to it. Which I'm sure is a result of my statically defined widths, which really needs to be more dynamic. How do I properly implement something like this, such that I end up with a view that I can reframe, pad, etc. as if it were something like a `Rectangle`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was fun :)  I suggest to draw the whole beam structure as a `Shape`. Then you can fill and clip the shape as needed, and also add padding etc.

I added two properties to define nr. of beams and relative center offset.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var beams: Double = 10
    @State private var offset: Double = 0.3

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Sunburst(beams: beams, centerOffset: offset)
                .fill(.orange)
                .background(.blue)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12))
            
                .frame(height: 200)
            
            Divider()
                .padding()
            
            Text("Nr of beams")
            Slider(value: $beams, in: 1.0...100.0)
            
            Text("Offset of center")
            Slider(value: $offset, in: 0...1)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct Sunburst: Shape {
    
    let beams: Double // nr of beams
    let centerOffset: Double // relative offset of centerpoint downwards, relative to height
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        let step = 180.0 / Double(beams)
        let centerOffsetAbs = rect.height * centerOffset
        
        let center = CGPoint(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height + centerOffsetAbs)
        let radius = max(rect.height, rect.width) * (1.5 + centerOffset)
        
        return Path { path in
            path.move(to: center)
            for angle in stride(from: step / 2, to: 180, by: 2 * step) {
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + cos(angle * Double.pi / 180) * radius, y: center.y - sin(angle * Double.pi / 180)  * radius ))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: center.x + cos((angle + step) * Double.pi / 180) * radius, y: center.y - sin((angle + step) * Double.pi / 180)  * radius ))
                path.addLine(to: center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```